# How I can get User.username and Group.name

Tags: django, inner-join, django-orm

I need to get the username and the name of group for all user.
The model that I use are User(default) and Group(default)

index.html:

```
{% for dato in usuarios %}
    {{dato.first_name|title}}
    {% for item in jefes %}
        {{dato.groups}}
    {% if dato.groups == item.id %} #I don't know to do this if
        {{item.name}}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

view:

```
def inicio(request):
    usuarios = User.Group.all()
    grupos = Group.objects.all()
    ctx = {'usuarios':usuarios,'grupos':grupos}
    return render_to_response('index.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: ****
    return render_to_response('index.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `groups` queryset from the view.

```
{% for dato in usuarios %}
    {{dato.first_name|title}}
    {% for group in dato.groups.all %}
        {{group.name}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: im sorry, jefes = grupos, i forgot change it
i need to show all users and your group name.